# Inserting Test into xslt file to make sure no values are blank

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I have the following XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets" xmlns:tagsLib="urn:tagsLib" xmlns:BlogLibrary="urn:BlogLibrary" xmlns:UCommentLibrary="urn:UCommentLibrary" xmlns:uForum="urn:uForum" xmlns:uForum.raw="urn:uForum.raw"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets tagsLib BlogLibrary UCommentLibrary uForum uForum.raw ">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
    <xsl:variable name="blognode" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(1187)" />
    <xsl:variable name="today" select="umbraco.library:CurrentDate()" />
    <xsl:variable name="later" select="umbraco.library:DateAdd($today, 'd', -3)" />
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="4" />


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <div id="slider" class="news_banner" >
      <xsl:for-each select="$blognode/ancestor-or-self::*//BlogPost [@isDoc and umbraco.library:DateGreaterThanOrEqual(PostDate, $later) ]">
        <xsl:sort select="pageViewCount" data-type="number" order="descending" />
        <xsl:if test="blogImage != ''">
          <xsl:variable name="crop" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(blogImage, 0)/crops/crops/crop [@name='NewsBanner']" />
          <xsl:if test="$crop/@url != '' and position() &lt;= $count" >
            <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}"><img src="{$crop/@url}" alt="{@nodeName}" title="#htmlcaption{@id}"  /></a>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
    <xsl:for-each select="$blognode/ancestor-or-self::*//BlogPost [@isDoc and umbraco.library:DateGreaterThanOrEqual(PostDate, $later) ]">
      <xsl:sort select="pageViewCount" data-type="number" order="descending" />
      <xsl:if test="blogImage != ''" >
        <xsl:variable name="crop" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(blogImage, 0)/crops/crops/crop [@name='NewsBanner']" />
        <xsl:if test="$crop/@url != '' and position() &lt;= $count">
          <div id="htmlcaption{@id}" class="nivo-html-caption"><xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" /> - <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">Full Story...</a></div>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I insert tests in here to insure that the entries are not blank.

Comment: Which entries are you speaking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I insert tests in here to
>   insure that the entries are not blank

Depends on what is meant by "blank".

**Here is a general way to determine** if the value of a particular expression (here denoted as `$var` for convenience) doesn't consist only of whitespace:

```
string-length(normalize-space($var)) > 0
```

**This can be made more general and flexible** if written as the equivalent:

```
string-length(translate($var, ' &#xA;&#xC;&#9;')) > 0
```

**The above can be used to check for `$var` not being blank if we have a different understanding of what "blank" should mean**. For example:

```
string-length(translate($var, ' &#xA;&#xC;&#9;&#xA0;')) > 0
```

tests if `$var` contains any other characters beside the white-space characters (space, new-line carriage return and tab) and the "non-breakable white-space character" (`&#xAO;`)